# Permutation-to-graph: surjective map?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Given is a permutation $P$ of $ \{ 1,\dots,n \} $. Convert it to a colored complete graph $G(P)=K_n$ as follows: The numbers $P_1,\dots,P_n$ are vertices, each pair $P_i,P_j (i<j)$ yields an edge $e$, and $e$ is colored green if $P_i<P_j$ and red otherwise.

Example: $P=[1,3,2,4]$. $G$ has five green edges, one red ($3,2$).

Clearly, simple counting shows information is lost (e.g. adding $0$ - and then increasing all indices by 1 - before or $n+1$ after any $P$ has the same effect - all green edges to a new vertex). But, is the map at least surjective - any bicolored $K_n$ yields at least one $P$ such that $G(P)=K_n$?

Comment: I think you are defining “permutation graphs” (take green to be an edge and red a non-edge) which are a small subclass of all graphs.

Comment: Here is the Wiki page for the permutation graphs that Gordon Royle mention, which indeed seems to be the right thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_graph

Comment: Indeed, the Wiki (implicitely) answers the question completely. Why, oh why didn't I google "permutation" "graph" "wiki"? (Probably because I never heard of permutation graphs before...)